# Running CiviCRM on WordPress.com?

Tags: wordpress.com

Has anyone run CiviCRM on WordPress.com?

In a chat with WordPress.com, they said it would run (given that you had the business plan which allows plugins).

However,  I feel like CiviCRM is more than just a typical WordPress plugin. :)

Comment: https://stats.civicrm.org/?tab=sites says there are ~2,800 WP sites with CiviCRM. And yes it is more than a typical WP Plugin. It is a whole CRM - with a level of 'potential' (or complexity) that WP itself offers

Answer (score 0):

https://stats.civicrm.org/?tab=sites says there are ~2,800 WP sites with CiviCRM.

And yes it is more than a typical WP Plugin. It is a whole CRM - with a level of 'potential' (or complexity) that WP itself offers.

Hosting of CiviCRM is also an important consideration: https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/planning/hosting/

Comment: I believe the OP's question has been misunderstood. They are asking about hosting Civicrm on WordPress.com. The quoted stats are about all WordPress installs, regardless of hosting arrangements.

Comment: I agree the OP was about hosting on wp.com - i was trying to add some helpful info about civicrm and WP in general - but since I don't have any knowledge specifically about hosting on wp.com i couldn't really comment on that aspect but thought I could try and nudge them in different hosting directions :-). maybe i needed to be blunter :-) Also I started it as a Comment but then thought 'what the hell' and threw it in as an Answer too.